# Implications of Code vs Input Initialization Cells in Package Files

Tags: packages, editing

When editing package files, I've noticed that there are really two options for how to format the cells, which has major implications for how they appear in the Mathematica front end.

One is to have them as `Code` styled cells, where no automatic identing, line wrapping, etc., is applied, which can make them very hard to read unless you spend a lot of time manually massaging the indentation or use an external tool or third-party package to do the indenting for you.

Alternatively, you can go through, make all the `Code` cells into `Input` cells, and then make all those `Input` cells into initialization cells, so they will still run if you click the "Run Package" button or if you `Get` the package. The `Input` cells will be line wrapped and appropriately indented automatically by the Front End.

Aside from the initial investment of effort to convert those cells to `Input` cells, it looks to me like it's by far the best option to be able to edit those package files in the Mathematica front end. Are there any implications of this approach that I haven't considered before I make it a guideline for my team?

Comment: It depends on programmer preference. Some like to control indentation, line breaks manually because they want the code to have a consistent appearance. Input cells are convenient, but these choices are made by the front end with minimal user control. You can always hold down the option/alt key, click on one cell to select all of the same type, and change them all at once, so going back and forth isn't too time consuming. Current versions also simplify indentation (select lines, hit tab), and there are formatting controls in the menu. There's no answer everyone will agree on.

Comment: The frontend sucks for large project. By 2023, there is still no simple functionalities like move lines up/down. The tab/untab is also inconvenient due to tab vs. blank issues. These are basic functionalities that almost all modern code editors have provided. I personally suggest you use third-party editors/IDEs for developing package/paclet, until MMA update their frontend......

Comment: As @jdp suggests, I use `Code` cells so I can hit `tab` to indent as I like it. It's not too bad, since new lines inherit the indentation level from the one above. Also the gray background looks nice ;)

Comment: @Lacia agreed that the front end is not terribly well-suited for large projects; the main downside to using an external IDE is that our IT department is very reluctant to allow us to install any software. It's been a multi-month process to just get Mathematica approved and running

Comment: Another advantage of Code cells vs. Input cells is that they are more friendly to version control systems as the line-breaks and indentation are not automatically determined...